# AD users that have specific word in the description field via Powershell

Tags: powershell, filter, get-aduser

I am new to PowerShell and I am trying to extract username and name of users that contain a word or specific words in the description field of an AD user.

In the description field we have added user job titles and I am trying to search for specific job titles to display full names and usernames.

What I have gathered from my quick googling is this:

`Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Description | Select Name,SamAccountName`

This displays all AD users with name and username details.

I believe this area I need to change is the -Filter but when I try something like this the command fails

`Get-ADUser -Filter -like "developer" -Properties Description | Select Name,SamAccountName`

This is probably going to be pretty straightforward for a powershell guy but I am struggling here.

Update to the command

`Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter 'Description -like "developer"' | Select Name,SamAccountName`

Nothing is getting outputted after I enter the command.

Further update the command that worked for me was:

`Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter 'Description -like "*developer*"' | Select Name,SamAccountName`

Comment: `Get-ADUser -Filter "Description -Like '*developer*'" -Properties Description`; this also may take a while depending on how many users you have, so I'd recommend narrowing down the search to an OU.

Comment: Thanks your comment helped my fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-Filter` Parameter:

```
Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter {Description -like "developer"}
OR
Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter 'Description -like "*developer*"'
```

Using `Where-Object`

```
Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter * | ? Description -match "developer"
```

Add your Final Select at the end of the pipeline if you just need this specific properties:

```
| Select Name,SamAccountName,Description
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help I tried the -filter parameter: Get-ADUser -Properties Description -Filter 'Description -like "developer"' | Select Name,SamAccountName nothing gets outputted so I tried the where-object parameter  Get-ADUser -Properties Description * | ? Description -match "developer" this fails cannot find an object with identity '*'

Comment: Update your select... add description.. check in the answer

Comment: Sorry I was my fault I was missing the additional * after developer so I entered * developer not * developer * thanks for your help on this it fixed the command.